# How to use a default Constructor genericly

Tags: java, generics, reflection, constructor

I wanna activate a default constructor in a generic way.

As in, getting an array of constructors and activating one of them (lets assume the first one is default).

The bit of code i wanna use it in is as so:

```
construct (Class clazz){
      .....
      List<Constructor> constructors=
      Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()).filter(X->X.isAnnotationPresent(Inject.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
           if(constructors.size()>1)
                    throw new MultipleInjectConstructorsException();
            else if(constructors.size()==0){
                    List<Constructor> defaultctor=
                    Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()).filter(X->X.getParameterCount()==0).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    if(defaultctor.size()==0)
                        throw new NoConstructorFoundException();
                    else {
                        /**activate the default constructor i got*/
                        //obj=defaultctor.get(0); 
        
                    }
                }
....
}
```

How can i use the default constructor which is in defaultctor.get(0)?

I think the question can be generalized even further.

How do i activate a method that have been recieved by reflection
if i know the name of the method and every info about it?

How can i activate it genericly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Constructor.newInstance` is the method that invokes a constructor instance. However, you'd almost certainly be better off using something like `Supplier` and a method reference of the form `MyType::new`.

Comment: Can i ask you a somewhat unrelated question?
can you dynamicly cast Field or a class  to Parameter as in: (Parameter) field or (Parameter) class?